# cannot read property ' ' of undefined in array

Tags: html, angular

AssetLiability.ts

`export class AssetLiability {
 public currentAsset: Array<{ accountNumber: string, price: string }> = Array( );
  }`

AssetLiabilityComponent.ts

export class AssetLiabilityComponent {

assetLiability: AssetLiability= new AssetLiability();

}

AssetLiabilityComponentUI.html

```
 <div *ngFor="let data of refactorJson.fieldLiabilityCurrentAsset  let i=index" >
    <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2 ">
      <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Account Number"
             [(ngModel)]="assetLiability.currentAsset[i].accountNumber" >
    </div>
     <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2 ">
      <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Account Number"
             [(ngModel)]="assetLiability.currentAsset[i].price" >
    </div>
    </div>

    cannot read property 'accountNumber' of undefined.
```

Comment: Please read about how to run for loop on html.

Comment: I think your array (currentAsset) is not initialized and it is getting undefined at first. And what is the value of i ?

Comment: now you can see my original code  .but still i am getting same error

Answer (score 0):

To use ngModel, you have to import FormsModule in app.module.ts.

Like this:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

 imports: [
    FormsModule
  ]
```

After you will add it, you can use ngModel freely in your app.

[How does it work?](https://appdividend.com/2018/10/03/angular-ngmodel-directive-example-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

As you wish to iterate over **currentAsset** you need to use a for loop :)

```
<div *ngFor="let a of assetLiability.currentAsset"> 
  <div class="row" >
      <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2 ">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Account Number"
              [(ngModel)]="a.accountNumber" >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2 ">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Account Number"
              [(ngModel)]="a.price" >
      </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: after added  ngfor also  i am getting same error .i

Comment: check this sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-muuvz6

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you instantiate your array `currentAsset` with no initial values passed to the `Array` constructor. Supposing you do not do any action to populate this array before trying to retrieve a value using an index, the error you get makes total sense. Lets break your code down at runtime.

Step 1: In `AssetLiabilityComponent` create a new class variable of type `AssetLiability` named `assetLiability` and you instantiate it.

Step 2: `new AssetLiability()` creates a class variable named `currentAsset`, that has objects of type `{ accountNumber: string, price: string }` and is instantiated with no values passed to the constructor.

**Here is your problem. When you instantiate an array via constructor with no initial values, it creates for you an empty array.**

Step 3: After Step 2 `assetLiability`'s initial value is

```
{ currentAsset: [] }
```

Step 4: Inside an iteration you are trying to access `assetLiability`'s `currentAsset` property (which is an empty array) and then trying to get an item out of it using an index. JS/TS tries to get this item for you, but since the array is empty it returns `undefined`

Final Step: `assetLiability.currentAsset[i]` is resolved to `undefined` and then JS tries to get the value of the `accountNumber` property.

The result is: `Cannot read property 'accountNumber' of undefined`.

So to fix your problem you have to either instantiate your array with initial values, or populate the array before it is accessed inside the iteration, or create a guard that checks for falsy values.